# Meaning and calligraphy style of two kanji?

Tags: meaning, translation, kanji, calligraphy

i was wondering what the meaning of these two kanji was and whether this kind of calligraphy style had a specific name. thanks for your help!

[image: two kanji done in calligraphy style]

Answer (score 2):

翔鶴 - it's apparently the name of a Japanese battleship. The meaning is soaring and crane.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_aircraft_carrier_Sh%C5%8Dkaku

I think the writing style is called [楷書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script). This is a broad category, so experts might be able to identify something narrower.

It could be a borrowed word from Chinese, but I don't know much about that.

Comment: thank you :) what a cool name for an aircraft carrier!